# ListView elements does not visible

Tags: android, json, listview, android-studio

I want to show JSON data in my page. But firstly, I create `tasks_row.xml` and than I create `tasks_layout.xml` for showing multiple row (multiple `tasks_row.xml` elements)

If I call `R.layout.tasks_row` in `Tasks_Fragment.java` this element shown but if I call `R.layout.tasks_layout` (for showing multiple rows) this page shown empty. Can anyone help me ?

tasks_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="13:00"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="71dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="10.12.2015"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Öngörülen Süre"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="35 DK."
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Gulay Uygun"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="i.mobile"
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Saş Cd, Turkey"
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView7" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="2423327"
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView9" />
```

Comment: @GülayUygun edit your question, and post your code in this.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use ListView instead of using multiple rows

Comment: may be there 1000 or more rows ?

Comment: That is the whole point of ListView it can have as many rows as you want (if implemented properly)

Answer (score 0):

Use recyclerview with adapter. Adapter implement item view and you can load as many items as you want.

Comment: I want to see my listview. I do not add any adapter yet. Is this problem to showing listview ?